# While loop entered when True or False

Tags: recursion, while-loop, python-3.8

When I run this function it's out put is continuous.

```py
def func(l):
    print(f' at begining not isnull{not isnull(l)}')
    while not isnull(l):
        print(f'in while loop isnull return is {isnull(l)}')
        islat(l[1:])
    return "At return."
```

Output that just runs on until I ctl-c.

```py
>>> func(["this"])
 At function begining: Not isnull(l) returns True
in while loop: Not isnull(l) returns True
 At function begining: Not isnull(l) returns False
in while loop: Not isnull(l) returns True
 At function begining: Not isnull(l) returns False
in while loop: Not isnull(l) returns True
 At function begining: Not isnull(l) returns False
in while loop: Not isnull(l) returns True
 At function begining: Not isnull(l) returns False
```

I do not understand why the while loop is entered when not isnull is True or False?

Comment: what is your isnull function

Comment: isnull test if isinstance list and is it empty.

Comment: what is islat funct

Comment: I think your mistake lies on your defined methods such as islat and isnull.  show those methods to know what you are doing there

Answer (score 0):

while loop will execute while the given expression is True. In your case, the given expression is `not isnull` . Since `isnull`  False, `not isnull` is  True, hence the loop executes untill `isnull` becomes True

Comment: I'm confused by it entering the while loop, at the first go, with the value True and then entering the while loop when the value is False, for the following times?